# Need to auto-login after logout on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, lightdm, autologin, kiosk

I've set up a kiosk using Ubuntu 12.04, and I'd like to have it autologin after a user logs out or if the screen locks, in case someone manages to get back to lightdm or tries to login to the non-kiosk account after a reboot. I've tried setting display-setup-script in lightdm.conf to run xautolock to trigger restarting lightdm, but that just causes Ubuntu startup in low graphics mode. So basically, if lightdm is active instead of a user being logged in, log in the kiosk user.

Answer (score 3):

Solution provided by [Marc Balmer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/77060/115476) causes restart dead locks on my system driven by systemd. So I've ended up with following setting at `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`:

```
session-cleanup-script=pkill -P1 -fx /usr/sbin/lightdm
```

The `lightdm` handles SIGTERM sent by `pkill` and gracefully shut downs and `systemd` makes service restarted.

Answer (score 1):

create the script below in e.g. `/etc/lightdm/restart` and make it executable (`chmod 755`), then enter the path to the script in `/etc/lightdm/lighdm.conf` as session-cleanup-script value:

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=unity-greeter
user-session=ubuntu
autologin-user=kiosk
autologin-user-timeout=10
allow-guest=no
session-cleanup-script=/etc/lightdm/restart
```

and here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap "" SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM
PATH=$PATH:/sbin:/usr/sbin
service lightdm restart
```

This will restart lightdm whenever someone logs out, restarting the auto-login process.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not wedded to `lightdm` in particular, then consider installing `nodm`, which is specifically designed for this kind of kiosk operation.  I've been using it on a couple of machines (a MythTV frontend and a Web browser) for many years without problems.

Comment: Note that the author of _nodm_ writes in the [README](https://github.com/spanezz/nodm#this-repository-is-not-maintained): _I do not use nodm anymore. I do not maintain nodm anymore.

To be really functional, nodm needs to be refactored to properly be a display manager with all that it requires in 2019 to be one. It currently does not make any effort to do so, and will break in obscure way as a result.

Nobody should really need nodm anymore: lightdm's autologin now does the right thing out of the box: please use that._

Answer (score 0):

In my case, in **/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf**:

```
session-cleanup-script=service lightdm restart
```

Comment: There's no reason to downvote this answer as the solution actually works. But you should put that line in a custom config file under the directory lightdm.conf.d/ instead of in the main config file. One line (under the heading `[Seat:*]` in the current version of lightdm). That's all it takes. No need for a separate script